# When do operations expire if not included?

Tags: operation

I read something somewhere about how the branch you specify in the operation allows you to set a hard limit, where after 64 blocks have passed after that branch, then if the operation isnt there, its just never allowed.

But I didn't see any constant in the list of constants that correspond to this.  This kind of consensus item seems like it'd be something worked as a constant.

So this branch and 64 blocks concept, is it a real thing after all?

Comment: Do you have the source by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently **240 as of Mumbainet**.

```
  let context = Raw_context.recover c in
  {
    Updater.context;
    fitness;
    message;
    max_operations_ttl = (Raw_context.constants c).max_operations_time_to_live;
    last_allowed_fork_level =
      Raw_level.to_int32 @@ Level.last_allowed_fork_level c;
  }
```

[image]

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_017_PtNairob/lib_protocol/alpha_context.ml
https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/016_mumbai.html#id1